# How to use layout create in code with arrayadapter in android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I  have this code here:

```
 CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(myActivity.this, R.layout.listitemrow,
                        catalogList);
 myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
 ....


 class CustomAdapter:


 public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public CustomAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> tweets){
                ....
    }
    ....
  }
```

listitemrow is xml in android layout folder.
For some reason, I don't want to use `R.layout.listitemrow`. I want to use mylayout created in code:

```
  public class myLayout extends RelativeLayout{
      .....
  }
```

Is there anyway to do this? Like this:

```
  CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(myActivity.this, new myLayout() ,
                            catalogList);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably override the `getView()` method of your adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    public CustomAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> tweets){
        ....
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemview = new myLayout(parent.getContext());
        ...
        return itemView;
    }

   ....
}
```